# Using numpy for the summation where i != j

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate the sum below where X is a matrix 2x5 and i/j is a selected column.

[image: sum]

I've solved this with the following code, but I would like to know if there is an easier solution with numpy to solve this sum (without the for..range)

```py
sum = 0
size = 5
for i in range(0, size):
    for j in range(0, size):
        if i != j:
            sum = sum + np.power(np.linalg.norm(X[:, i] - X[:, j]), 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can optimize quite a bit here. First, you only need to compute for off-diagonal elements of the full i-j matrix. Second, you can compute for just one half of the matrix and double the sum, since `norm(a - b) == norm(b - a)`.

Use `np.triu_indices` (or `np.tril_indices`):

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(size, 1)
sum = 2 * (np.linalg.norm(X[:, i] - X[:, j], axis=0)**2).sum()
```

You can avoid the square roots (assuming you're using 2-norm):

```
sum = 2 * (X[:, i] - X[:, j])**2).sum(None)
```

Answer (score -1):

`(np.array([np.subtract.outer(X,X)[0,:,0,:],np.subtract.outer(X,X)[1,:,1,:]])**2).sum()`

seems to work .... I'd definitely stick with the for loops (or if this were time-critical production code, I'd probably use Cython ... This "solution" does involve more computations than it needs to).

However, removing *one* for loop can be done quite a bit more cleanly:

```
sum = 0
size = 5
XT = X.T
for i in range(0, size):
    sum = sum + ((XT[i, :] - XT[:, :])**2).sum()
```

... Also it's not a good idea to use sum as a variable name. It overrides the built-in sum function!

Comment: A few additional pointers here:
 * The `if i != j:` check is not needed as the sum is 0 in that case and so can be included without changing the answer.
 * Using linalg.norm and then taking the square is like doing `((x**2)**0.5)**2`; just computing this directly is quicker.